# The Elder/the Younger vs. Senior/Junior

Tags: names

"The elder" and "the younger" are often used for historical figures instead of Junior and Senior. Is that intended to imply that they are not a father and son, or is that the accepted usage for historical figures from the ancient Roman period?

Comment: Well, Pliny the Younger was the nephew of Pliny the Elder, but British PM Pitt the Younger _was_ the son of Pitt the Elder, so I don't think any implication is intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

William Pitt the Younger was Prime Minister of Great Britain from 1783 to 1801 and was only 24 when he took office but that is not why he was called 'Younger'. He was called 'Younger' because he was the son of William Pitt the Elder, who was the informal leader of the British Cabinet from 1756 to 1761, so the adoption of the titles is not confined to Roman times.

[William Pitt the Younger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Pitt_the_Younger)